# how to call function of function in react native from the global function

Tags: javascript, react-native

i Created the native module and module.export function calling after every 3 min so i can split audio, but i want to call this updateState function, How can i call updateState function.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import {
    Text
} from 'react-native';

module.exports = async (taskData) => {
    updateState({})
}

const myTask = () => {

    const updateState = () => {}

    return (<Text>Hello</Text>)
};

export default myTask;
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the `useEffect` hook provided by react.

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';

const myTask = () => {
    
  useEffect(() => {
     updateState()
  });
    
  return (<Text>Hello</Text>)
 };

export default myTask;
```

https://en.reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html check the doc here.

Comment: I tried this but it will call function infinite, and useEffect can access only inside the function, i want to access updateState function out side of main function.

Comment: what do you mean outside of main function? useEffect will be called everytime this component rendered. if you want it to be called once, or more time in different times, you have to use state. your question is not very clear

Comment: sorry for that, in above code that i shared the updateState is a function that is in the main function "myTask", is it possible to call updateState function outside of myTask ?

Comment: No, you need to know what is scope in JS. You created `updateState` inside `myTask` component, you can't use it in upper level. For these purpose, you can create an util and use it in your component file, but without knowing what's your final aim i can't help you more than this

Comment: aim is to call the function from headlessJs to check my audio is recording or not